# Run Javascript on the specific process id of Safari

Tags: macos, safari, applescript

I have the script like this here:

```
on run argv
    set pid to item 1 of argv
    set fileLocation to item 2 of argv
    tell application "System Events"
        set theprocs to every process whose unix id is pid
        repeat with proc in theprocs
            set the frontmost of proc to true
            using terms from application "Safari"
                set theScript to "document.querySelector(\"input[name='fileField']\").click()"
                tell application "Safari" to do JavaScript theScript in current tab of first window
            end using terms from
            tell proc
                keystroke "G" using {command down, shift down}
                delay 2
                key code 51
                delay 2
                keystroke fileLocation
                delay 10
                key code 52
                delay 5
                key code 52
                delay 5
            end tell
        end repeat
    end tell

end run
```

which is trying to do the file upload process on the Safari browser. The main goal is to run the script against the given process id ( as many Safari will be running on the machine).

I have problem here with the line `do JavaScript` from:

```
tell application "Safari" to do JavaScript theScript in current tab of first window
```

this is executing the click call on the different Safari browser, rather than the one given in the `pid`.

I just want to make sure that the script runs against the given Safari PID.

How can I do that?

Comment: It will probably help to specify why there are many different Safaris running on the machine. If it’s because other users are logged in, that shouldn’t be an issue: AppleScript can only target the Safari for the current user.

Comment: Its belong to same user. The reason why there are many safari running is Selenium automation open them in a different browser.